# Definite integral with exponential and modified Bessel function

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

Currently I am stuck with the following integral:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{x_{\rm th}} \frac{2x_1}{\sigma^2} e^{-\frac{x_1^2}{\sigma^2(1-\mu _2^2)}} I_0\left (\frac {2~\mu_2x_{\rm th}x_1}{\sigma^2(1-\mu_2^2)} \right) \,dx_1,
\end{equation}
where $\sigma,x_{\rm th}>0$, $\mu_2 \in [0,1]$, and $I_0(\cdot)$ is the zero-order modified Bessel function of the first kind.

I have obtained a solution by considering the following series expansion: $I_v(z)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!\:\:\Gamma(v+k+1)}\left( \frac{z}{2} \right)^{v+2k}$, from Gradshteyn. But now I am trying to obtain a solution in terms of some well-defined functions and not any series decomposition.

My solution with the series decomposition:

\begin{align}
&\int_0^{x_{\rm th}} x_1 \exp \left(-\frac {x_1^2}{\sigma ^{2}(1-\mu^2)} \right) I_{0}\left ({\frac {2\mu x_{\rm th}x_1}{\sigma ^{2}(1-\mu^2)}}\right) \, dx_1 \\[6pt]
= {} & \int_0^{x_{\rm th}} x_1 \exp \left(-\frac {x_1^2}{\sigma ^{2}(1-\mu^2)} \right) \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k!)^2}\left(\frac {\mu x_{\rm th}x_1}{\sigma ^{2}(1-\mu^2)} \right)^{2k} \, dx_1 \\[6pt]
= {} & \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k!)^2} \left(\frac {\mu x_{\rm th}}{\sigma ^{2}(1-\mu^2)} \right)^{2k} \int_0^{x_{\rm th}} \exp \left(-\frac {x_1^2}{\sigma^{2}(1-\mu^2)} \right) x_1^{2k+1} \, dx_1 \\[6pt]
= {} & \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\mu x_{\rm th} \right)^{2k}}{(k!)^2 \left( \sigma ^{2}(1-\mu^2) \right)^{k-1}} \left( \Gamma(k+1)-\Gamma \left( k+1, \frac{x_{\rm th}^2}{\sigma^{2}(1-\mu^2)} \right) \right).
\end{align}

Any help or lead in this case will be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You should always go for minimal working examples in asking questions; consolidate any constants into single constants. In your case, I think you have $\int_0^a b x e^{-cx^2} I_0(dx) \, \mathrm{d} x$ (and all four of those numbers are distinct, even if some of them are related).

Comment: Anyway, if you have a solution from series expansion, you should write the series you get out of doing that.

Comment: @Ian, I completely agree with you. But I have written the exact expression, as I thinking if this may help in transforming the integral to any standard form.

Comment: I guess you actually have a sum of error functions when you do the series expansion (since it's a finite integral)...as a place to start with fishing for an expression, I'd consider twiddling parameters in such a way that the upper limit goes to $\infty$. Then at least the error functions go away.

Comment: @Ian I have now stated my series-based solution in the question itself.

Comment: After doing some variable transformations you essentially end up with the integral
$$\int_0^xz\exp(-z^2)I_0(tz)\mathrm dz$$
Unfortunately, this integral does not appear in DLMF so I am doubtful for a nice form.